# Can I enter Switzerland from Turkey, on a UK passport with a long stay French working visa? I am vaccinated

Tags: uk, france, turkey, switzerland, working-visas

I am planning on heading from the UK to Turkey on the 20th of Nov and then from Turkey to Geneva on the 25th. From Geneva, my employer will take us across to France. Is this possible?

I am a UK citizen with a working visa for my time in France. This visa states 'multiple entry' and does not state a port of origin for travel to France.
I am fully vaccinated and have the necessary paperwork etc.

So in short, UK -> Turkey -> Switzerland -> overland to France.

Comment: This https://travelcheck.admin.ch/home should help answer that question

Comment: The Swiss Government has a website where you just answer a few questions, and then are told whether you can enter, and if so, under what conditions. It is here: https://travelcheck.admin.ch/home

Comment: @Willeke: This is a constantly evolving situation. A good answer is supposed to be helpful when someone finds it as the result of a search half a year from now. So presenting a snapshot of what the rules are at a narrow point in time is not usufull.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are changing daily, sometimes even hourly. As such it is not very useful to present here what the rules are at the moment this answer is being written. They may be different tomorrow.

So the best thing to do is head over to the official Swiss Government Travelcheck website. You can find that here:

https://travelcheck.admin.ch/home

On this site you just answer a few questions, and will get an answer as to which regulations govern your entry at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Entering your information into https://travelcheck.admin.ch/home, either with

- B/C Visa, where you won't be asked vaccination status, or
- "Other" in the Entry Requirements section and then selecting "vaccinated" (I tried either Comirnaty or Astra Zeneca), "coming from Turkey", "have been in UK and Turkey", and "for transit to another country with leaving the airport" yield the same result:

[image: Travelcheck Result]

Searching the pages reachable from the first "read more" link of this result page leads to the exemption of the second test and possible quarantine requirements laid out here in [Art. 8f](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/2021/61/en#art_8): "persons who enter Switzerland for the purpose of transiting the country and who intend and are able to travel on directly to another country;"

So you need a test for entry and have to register. But it seems to be possible at the moment.

Comment: Switzerland does not issue B visas (nor does any Schengen country), and C visas are airport transit visas needed by and issued to citizens of a small lost of countries that does not include the UK.  Therefore, by "B/C visa," I think you mean "B/C residence permit," which is not relevant here since only foreigners resident in Switzerland can have one of those.  The visa here will be a D visa issued by France.